# Array difference for multidimensional array with single array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want difference of multidimensional array with single array. I dont know whether it is possible or not. But my purpose is find diference.

My first array contain username and mobile number

```
array1
(
array(lokesh,9687060900),
array(mehul,9714959456),
array(atish,9913400714),
array(naitik,8735081680)
)
```

`array2(naitik,atish`)

then I want as result

```
result( array(lokesh,9687060900), array(mehul,9714959456) )
```

I know the function **array_diff($a1,$a2);** but this not solve my problem. Please refer me help me to find solution.

Comment: curly bracket are just for array. I am changing in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
    $array1 = array(array('lokesh',9687060900),
    array('mehul',9714959456),
    array('atish',9913400714),
    array('naitik',8735081680));

    $array2 = ['naitik','atish'];

    $result = [];
        foreach($array1 as $val2){

        if(!in_array($val2[0], $array2)){
            $result[] = $val2;
        }
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You forgot !in_array (not sign)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` or a simple `foreach` loop:

```
$arr = [ ['lokesh', 9687060900],
         ['mehul', 9714959456],
         ['atish', 9913400714],
         ['naitik', 8735081680] ];

$rem = ['lokesh', 'naitik'];

$result = array_filter($arr, function ($i) use ($rem) {
    return !in_array($i[0], $rem); });

print_r ($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_filter` and `in_array` functions:

```
$array1 = [
    array('lokesh', 9687060900), array('mehul', 9714959456),
    array('atish', 9913400714),  array('naitik', 8735081680)
];
$array2 = ['naitik', 'atish'];

$result = array_filter($array1, function($item) use($array2){
    return !in_array($item[0], $array2);
});

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => lokesh
            [1] => 9687060900
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => mehul
            [1] => 9714959456
        )
)
```

The same can be achieved by using a regular `foreach` loop:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item[0], $array2)) $result[] = $item;
}
```